# Read the XML/SOAP from an XMLDocument

Tags: .net, xml, soap

I assume somehow you can user an XmlReader to read the envelope from an XmlDocument.  Does anyone have a good example how?  I want to simply extract the entire sent SOAP text into a string variable so we can log it in case of a request error.

Example methods:

```
protected virtual HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string endPoint, Int32 contentLength)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_requestURI);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = contentLength;
    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";

    return request;
}


public Response.Response SendRequest()
{
    XmlDocument doc = CreateRequestXML();

    // Determins if API call needs to use a session based URI
    string requestURI = UseAuthURI ? _requestURIAuthBased + sID : _requestURI;

    byte[] data = XmlUtil.DocumentToBytes(doc);

    // Create the atual Request instance
    HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(requestURI, data.Length);
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.Timeout = 30000;

    // Send the Request
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    // get response
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
            throw new Exception(message);
        }

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream))
            {
                return CreateResponse(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the situation? ASMX service? WCF? How are you going to get your hands on the XML?

Comment: I'm confused. What is it that you want to do? Just log to a file? Use XmlDocument.Save or .WriteTo.

Comment: In want to create a property in my Request abstract class that holds the SOAP that's being sent across the wire

Comment: as far as I remember, trying to log the actual XML being sent back and forth using HttpWebRequest/WebResponse is a lot more involved than you'd think. We had to resort to subclassing the request/response mechanism and tweak all sorts of crazy stuff. **MUCH** easier if you'd be using WCF :-)

Comment: If you really had a XML document, you can just grab the `.OuterXml` property - that contains all the XML for the XmlDocument.

Comment: well I can't do it in the response, because then I'd have to append the soap text to the response error if it errors out.  I don't want to do it that way, it's sort of messy.  I want the soap sent separated out into a nice property on the request in case the response fails.

Comment: I'll try the .OuterXml....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using doc.OuterXML works.